# Create selectors with no declaration

Tags: sass

I am planning to use SASS by creating [_partial] and use [@import].

**Question:** How can I create selectors with no declaration?.

I will of course populate the selectors with declaration,
but that input comes from the other [_partials]. Have I understood correctly that SASS will delete a selector that has no declaration? Is there any workaround?

My partials structure looks as below.

- @import '_1-partial_variables.sass'
- @import '_2-partial_divs_only.sass'
- @import '_3-partial_wrapper.sass'
- @import '_4-partial_divs_layout.sass'

**What I have tried so far:**

In [_2-partial_divs_only.sass] I have tried:

```
.div-1
```

(the build executes without errors, but the div itself is not created).

```
.div-1 {};
```

(the build script says, "Error: Expected newline".

**What about same scenarios using SCSS as source file?**

The results are exactly same, a selector with blank declaration, is not created.

My build-line is:

```
sass --no-source-map main.sass main.css
```

Comment: Sass will not delete CSS rule without styles (e.g. `.foo {}`)

Comment: @Flying According to this reported SASS issue, it will delete it: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2069

Comment: thank you, I was wrong at this point

Comment: I added an answer that does work (the selector is being created), but it creates an unwanted comment structure. If an SASS user can better confirm that the nature of SASS is to delete selectors with blank declaration, and find a better workaround, please share the info.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this works in order for the SASS compiler to create the selector [.div-1]:

```
.div-1
  /*! keep */
```

This works also:

```
.div-1
  /**/
```

As the source is a SASS file, I do not add [{}] nor [;].

Those characters are being created automatically when building from SASS to CSS.